# BlackBerry playbook simulator on VMWare player suspends

Tags: vmware, blackberry-playbook

I installed the BlackBerryPlayBookSimulator-Installer-1.0.8-6067-Win-201112052354 On windows7 and try to play on the VMWare player it suspends like on the following picture.

[image] Please Help me. I reinstalled the VMWare but it did n't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried running the simulator under VMware Workstation 8 on several of my machines. The only machines it actually works on are the ones with fancy graphics cards. On all others, it freezes at "Starting screen".